# Group Policy - Transferring to another domain

Tags: group-policy, rds

I am in the process of setting up two RDS servers in different locations on different domains, I've set one up and I am very happy with it, it looks like a windows 7 desktop and its really fast so I would like to transfer this environment to another domain so I don't have to go through the process of setting up group policys etc, is it possible to transfer all these setting in the current state and import them into a new domain, I know I can export the group policy for back up purpose but not so sure about importing into completely new environment, would be nice to have two projects finished! any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely do exactly what you want - it's how I do most of my projects. Take a backup of the old domain GPO's and take the whole folder with you.

Then, on the new domain, create a GPO, right click and choose 'Restore from backup' and go from there - you will be asked to find the folder from before and, when you do, will be presented with a list of GPO's. The new policy can be any name, by the way.

Finally, run through it and ensure you haven't left any domain specific stuff. By the way, this method will bring over scripts, policy preferences and so on. It's a great time saver.

Remember to fix any unresolved SIDs / GUIDs such as the GPO's security descriptors.

Comment: Excellent, I wasn't 100% sure it was possible the SIDS were my main concern, how would I fix them, just delete and recreate ?

Comment: @JJJJNR Exactly!